# Find an analytic function $w=u+iv$ such that $u=\frac{x(1-x^2-y^2)}{4x^2y^2+(1+y^2-x^2)^2}, w(0)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, holomorphic-functions

> Find an analytic function $w=u+iv$ such that 
>   $$
> u=\frac{x(1-x^2-y^2)}{4x^2y^2+(1+y^2-x^2)^2}, w(0)=0
> $$

This is the assignment under b.) and on a.) the answer is given to use the substitutions:
$$x=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}; y=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}.$$
the answer here is suppose to be:
$\frac{z}{1-z^2}$ and just cannot seem to get this. When simplifying the expression with these substitutions I get:

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{(z+\overline{z})(1-z\overline{z})}{1-(z^2+{\overline{z}}^2)+\frac{(z^2+{\overline{z}}^2)^2}{4}-\frac{(z+\overline{z})^2(z-\overline{z})^2}{4}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying the denominator gives
$$
u = \frac{(z + \bar{z})(z\bar{z}-1)}{2(z^2-1)(\bar{z}^2-1)}
$$
You can then separate the denominator to get
$$
u = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z}{z^2-1} + \frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z}^2-1}\right)
$$
This is clearly the real part of the analytic function $z/(z^2-1)$, as desired.

Comment: I have tried very hard to simplify this, but couldn't. Could you help with that?

Comment: Repeatedly use the difference of squares identity: $(z^2+\bar{z}^2)^2 - (z-\bar{z})^2(z+\bar{z})^2 = (z^2+\bar{z}^2)^2 - (z^2-\bar{z}^2)^2 = (z^2+\bar{z}^2 + z^2 - \bar{z}^2)(z^2 +\bar{z}^2-z^2+\bar{z}^2) = 4z^2\bar{z}^2$